# How do I connect slot to user defined variable in Qt?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find an answer to my question. Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to use a QSlider to manipulate data in a class I created.

In the main window constructor I have the following:

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

With a slot defined in the same class:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    AFrame *frame;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public slots:
    void setValue(int val)
    {
        frame->setMphValue(val);
    }

};
```

My frame class is a promoted widget to allow for drawing over the image I have set and is defined as follows:

```
class AFrame : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AFrame( QWidget *parent );
    void setMphValue(int val) { m_mph = val; }

protected:
    void paintEvent( QPaintEvent *event );

private:
    int m_mph;

};
```

The problem is that when I try assigning the m_mph value in the paintEvent function of the AFrame class, the integer value is lost.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? Is there a better way to approach this problem?

And my paintEvent code:

```
void AFrame::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{

    QLabel::paintEvent(event);
    QPainter painter(this);

    QPen pen("#FF0099");
    pen.setWidth(8);


    painter.setPen(pen);

    //rpm
    painter.drawLine(250,275,165,165);

    //oil
    painter.drawLine(450,100,400,75);

    //fuel
    painter.drawLine(650,95,600,65);

    //mph

    QRect rec(0,0,125,3);

    int velocity = m_mph;
    int rpmStartVal = -225;
    float mph = velocity * 1.68;

    painter.translate(870,275);
    painter.rotate(rpmStartVal + mph);

    painter.drawRect(rec);


 }
```

Comment: Are you sure the setValue function gets called? If the connection fails Qt usually complains through debug output.

Comment: I don't have the debugger working to step through it, but I am not getting the "no such slot" error that I've seen before and I'm not getting any other warnings, so I am assuming it gets called.

Comment: "when I try assigning the m_mph value in the paintEvent function" You're not doing that, you are assigning it in the `setMphValue(int)` method.  If `AFrame` isn't changing when you move the slider, you will need to call `update()` in `setMphValue(int)`.

Comment: It is my experience that assumptions nearly always lead to additional pain. If you can't get the debugger to work use debug output like `qDebug() << "foo" << val` to see what gets called.

Comment: Thanks for that tip Georg. Yes, the function is being called and the value is being updated, but it is not repainting the screen each time this value changes, which is what I want it to do. I added an update() call to the setMphValue(int) and I have one at the end of the paintEvent method. Do I need to call it somewhere else also?

Comment: You could call the `repaint()` function explicitly at the end of `setMphValue()`.

Comment: @user1430512 Do NOT call `update()` in `paintEvent()`!  `update()` puts a `repaint()` request into the event queue, which calls `paintEvent()`.

Comment: @user1430512 Post your `paintEvent()` code.

Comment: @user1430512 the code you posted is not the code we want. Post implementation of classes too.

Comment: cbamber85 you should post your comment as answer, as it will surely resolve the problem. Every change in property that is somehow change widget look should be followed by `update()` call

Comment: I think what you want is actually `void setValue(int val) { frame->setMphValue(val); frame->update; }`

Comment: I added my paintEvent code above. I changed my code to only include the update from the setMphValue() method. The varible's value is lost once the paint event is called. I'm overriding the paintEvent for QLabel. Is that why this is happening?

Comment: Ok, `m_mph` is only set once and used once in the code you have provided.  Are you _sure_ (either through a debugger, or printing text) that the variable is being assigned the value you expect, and that it is different once inside `paintEvent()`?  If so, you must be modifying it elsewhere in code you have not provided.

Answer (score 2):

The integer value is not being lost. The widget has no magical insight into the fact that it should repaint when the `mph` value is updated. Your `setMphValue` should look like below. That's all there's to it.

```
void setMphValue(int val) {
   m_mph = val;
   update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Kuba's reply:

You should also check whether `val` is the same value as previous, in order to avoid avoid repainting when it's not actually necessary - and side-effect infinite loops should anything called by `update()` later touch `setMphValue()`.

In full:

```
void setMphValue(int val) {
   if (val == m_mph) return;
   m_mph = val;
   update();
}
```