# Qt, how to update GUI every loop step

Tags: c++, qt, loops, user-interface

My main looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Window window(&a);

    return a.exec();
}
```

And Window class has a method move() which looks like this:

```
void Window::move()
{

    const int STEPS_AMOUNT = 10;
    const int STEP = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < STEPS_AMOUNT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < STEP; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < SQUARES_AMOUNT; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < SQUARES_AMOUNT; l++)
                {
                    int r = qrand() % 2;
                    if (r == 0)
                        r = -1;
                    board[k][l] = r;
                }
            }
            QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
            app->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
        }
    }
}
```

And I would just like to paint my board every time "j" increases.
To do so I created this method:

```
void Window::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(e);

    for (int k = 0; k < SQUARES_AMOUNT; k++)
        for (int l = 0; l < SQUARES_AMOUNT; l++)
        {
            if (board[k][l] == 1)
                draw(k, l);
        }
}
```

I thought one of those 2 lines:

```
        QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
        app->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
```

is going to work according to the definition that processEvents():

> Processes all pending events for the calling thread according to the
>   specified flags until there are no more events to process.

But it didnt work. How to do so? I dont want to update GUI with time step.

Comment: Calling `processEvents` manually is usually a major code smell and indicates a design problem. Normally you should just let the main event loop take care of processing events.

Answer (score 0):

It's some time since I've done any Qt development. The Qt way of doing this is to use signals and slots. Look at the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849149/how-do-i-connect-slot-to-user-defined-variable-in-qt) for an example.

The Qt documentation is [here](http://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

To summarize, you `connect` your data source to the widget (or a wrapper if the widget can't display that type directly). This is done during your setup.

Then at runtime, you call `emit` which causes the connection to fire.

You will also need to do something like an `update` for each refresh. If you just send 1000 different strings to the widget then I don't think that the UI will display every one.